# Table cell only is highlighted when you tap on the disclosure icon

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I place a single table view cell on my view using interface builder and add an accessory type, a selection color and enable user interaction.

[image]

My problem is that the cell only is highlighted when the user taps on the arrow icon. But it also should be highlighted when the user taps on the text label inside it, he can tap anywhere on the cell.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: From the wording of your question, it sounds like you are just using  a single cell in your view, not associated with a UITableView.  Is that true and if so, why?

Comment: why should I use a UITableView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A UITableViewCell is really only meant to be used within the context of a UITableView (which knows how to handle and/or delegate the selection & highlighting of the cell).

Having a UITableViewCell outside of the context of a table is a somewhat unexpected user interface.

Couldn't you do what you want to do with a UIButton instead?

Or a UIView that has two UIButton subviews (or at least one UIButton subview to contain a widget graphic that looks like the disclosure accessory)?  That way the things you want to get highlighted would definitely happen, as opposed to depending on a nonexistent [UITableView didSelectCellAtIndexPath:] method that doesn't exist in a view that isn't a UITableView delegate.